# imagepng error while converting string to image

Tags: php, image-processing

i am converting string into image and want to give that location of image in meta

i have this code but this gives me error

> PHP Warning:  imagepng() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in

```
   <?php 

   $randimagefilename=rand(1000,100000000);

     $tempDir = '/temp';
     $fileName = $tempDir.$randimagefilename.'.png';



    header("Content-type: image/png");

    $string = 'hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii how are you what is going on ';

  $font  = 8;
   $width  = imagefontwidth($font) * strlen($string);
   $height = imagefontheight($font);

 $image = imagecreatetruecolor ($width,$height);
  $white = imagecolorallocate ($image,255,255,255);
  $black = imagecolorallocate ($image,0,0,0);
 imagefill($image,0,0,$white);

  imagestring ($image,$font,0,0,$string,$black);

  imagepng($image, $fileName); 

imagedestroy($image);


    echo' <meta name="image_src" content="'.$fileName.'" />';
  ?>
```

where i am doing mistake.please advise

Comment: hint: $img is never used, except in `imagepng()`.

Comment: @DenisV there was some copy/paste error corrected the uestion.same error

Comment: Add a slash `$tempDir = '/temp/';` - Right now, your image is being interpreted as `tempimage1888423092.png` instead of the intended `temp/image1888423092.png` which would explain the error. Let me know if you want that posted as an answer ;) let's just hope somebody doesn't come along and feeds off my comment.

Comment: Plus, you may also want to use a relative path, or a full server path. I.e.: `$tempDir = 'temp/';` or `$tempDir = '../temp/';` depending on the code's location of execution. As a full system path: `$tempDir = '/var/user/you/httpdocs/temp/';`

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks i have tried.it was permission error.now i am able to fetch the image and location as well but the complete webpage is being blocked by that meta image dont know what is the problem

Comment: You're welcome. Therefore, the question should still be considered as "open" then. Plus, why the use of `<meta name="image_src" content`, what is it being used for, social media?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes u r right.u can give that as answer

Comment: Just the `Add a slash $tempDir = '/temp/';` or the one below it too `Plus, you may also want to use a relative path, or a full server path. I.e.: $tempDir = 'temp/';`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- give as answer so that i canaccept

Comment: It has been posted, *cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a slash to the end of the folder's name: `$tempDir = '/temp/';`

Right now, your image is being interpreted as `temp56385145.png.png` instead of the intended `temp/56385145.png.png` (as an example number taken from a test I did.)

Plus, you may also want to use a relative path.

I.e.: `$tempDir = 'temp/';` or `$tempDir = '../temp/';`
depending on the code's location of execution.

Or as a full system path: `$tempDir = '/var/user/you/httpdocs/temp/';`